# Query by Max Date Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm working on a spreadsheet that records logistics reports via a google form. We have 100 locations and logistics personal visit and report on condition of each location, i.e. the location needs maintenance etc.

We have 3 categories of location: Priority locations that need to be visited daily, secondary locations that need to be visited a minimum every other day, and other locations that we aim to visit a minimum of every 3 days.

Each logistics visit is recorded in the spreadsheet via the form it captures:

```
Column A = Time Stamp,  
Column B = Location,  
Column C = Damage Yes/No,  
Column D = Damage Description,  
Column E = Personnel ID,
```

I want to create a query that shows only the last visit for each location where that date is older than 3 days. If it's been visited to day or yesterday I don't want it to show up, and as we visit each location multiple times I only want to show 1 entry for each location, the latest entry.

This is what I've attempted:

```
=Query(LogisticsReports, " SELECT A, B, J WHERE A < TODAY()-3 ",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Try

```
=QUERY(
   LogisticsReports,
   "SELECT A,B,J WHERE A < date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",
   1
)
```

## Explanation

QUERY use [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). It handles dates differently than Google Sheets, so the result of functions that returns a date should be convert to a string having yyyy-mm-dd date format and have to be preceded by the date keyword.

Comment: That's great!   
I changed to A> date, that works better for what I want.
Now I want to try and group the answers by location. Where would I add GROUP by   =QUERY(
   LogisticsReports,
   "SELECT A,B,J WHERE A < date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-3,"yyyy-mm-dd") GROUP by B &"'",
   1
)

Comment: Thinking about it, this will not show locations that have a date older than TODAY()-3.  But I want to ensure that the most recent date for each location is visible no matter what even if it's older than TODAY()-3

Comment: Comments are intended for to criticize or to ask clarification regarding a question or answer. Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions.